# How to convert x, y points to long, lat using GDAL

Tags: gdal

I'm intending to convert centroid (x, y) to long, lat using GDAL library. What I did actually, first I created a multiple features (veg,buildings,waterbody) shapefile then I find out the centroid of the polygons(veg,buildings,waterbody) using GDAL so now I have to convert this (x,y) points to coordinates(GCS) using GDAL? How can I do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you wish to clip a raster window around each of your points, but you need to get your points to lat-long first.

Comment: Your centroids are geodata, and so when you created them, you created them within a certain coordinate system. If you did so in Google Earth, the coordinate system is (IIRC) Web Mercator.

Comment: These are the centroids POINT (666654.85960785 1060246.0012435)
POINT (658982.091628625 1054604.09402387)
POINT (652509.7474056 1060385.45856754)

Comment: In what program? ArcGIS? USGS probably uses UTM as a projection, but which UTM zone would depend on where your image was for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

Comment: Any time there's an "and" in the question title, the question is likely to see greater scrutiny, due to our One question per Question policy. Here you have multiple tasks, and you don't show what you have attempted, making it more difficult to determine how to help. If you rollback edits for incorrect English usage, you'll start to accumulate downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create a square buffer in a vector format:

```
# set the radius for the plots
radius <- 20 # radius in meters
# define the plot edges based upon the plot radius. 
yPlus <- centroids$northing+radius
xPlus <- centroids$easting+radius
yMinus <- centroids$northing-radius
xMinus <- centroids$easting-radius

# calculate polygon coordinates for each plot centroid. 
square=cbind(xMinus,yPlus,  # NW corner
    xPlus, yPlus,  # NE corner
    xPlus,yMinus,  # SE corner
    xMinus,yMinus, # SW corner
    xMinus,yPlus)  # NW corner again - close ploygon
# Extract the plot ID information
ID=centroids$Plot_ID
```

Source: https://www.neonscience.org/field-data-polygons-centroids

Comment: The asker asks how to solve the problem using gdal, not R.

Comment: That was not clear--I thought the R gdal package was being used: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html